# Conditional formatting on multiple columns in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, conditional-formatting

I have several columns with similar data.  I see how to apply conditional formatting to single columns in Power BI Tables and matrices, but I'd like to apply across multiple columns, so that the highest value in multiple columns is darkest.  Tips on how to accomplish this?  I am new to Power Bi so perhaps I am missing the obvious.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Avoid cross-tables in Power BI and don't use a table but a matrix visual.